# Is derivative of a Gaussian Signal also Gaussian? How to find variance of signal that is obtained from differentiation of a Gaussian signal?

Tags: normal-distribution, gaussian-process, gaussian-mixture-distribution, kalman-filter, particle-filter

Could someone please let me know or give appropriate references for the question I have posed above. 
My main interest lies in applying Kalman filter for state estimation. The noise on sensor measurements is assumed gaussian. 
However, the expression (output vector) also has terms that are derivative of the measurements. 
I need to find the approximation of the noise and hence, variance of that expression . Could i assume the derivative of noise term to be Gaussian also?..If yes, what should be the mean value and associated variance?
Could some appropriate references be given ?
MAny many thanks in advance.

Comment: Differentiation is a linear operation, and linear ops applied to gaussians are gaussian.

Comment: Take a look at section 9.4 of http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW9.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect the differentiated Gaussian noise remain to be Gaussian distributed. However, its spectrum content would be changed. It's no longer flat (white). The low frequency content is filtered out.